# EntityFramework ToDictionary causes "Index was outside the bounds of the array"

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework to connect to a table called `Modules`, and then I need to convert these to a dictionary like so:

```
'get the modules and convert to a dictionary keyed by id and return
dim dict = context.Modules.ToDictionary(Function(x) x.Id)
```

This usually works, but sometimes on this line of code I get this exception:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.GetEnumerator
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.Linq.InternalSet`1.Initialize
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.GetEntitySetAndBaseTypeForType
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.TryUpdateEntitySetMappingsForType
>   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.UpdateEntitySetMappings
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.GetEdmSpaceType
>   System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace.TryGetEdmSpaceType
>   System.Data.Mapping.DefaultObjectMappingItemCollection.TryGetMap
>   System.Data.Mapping.DefaultObjectMappingItemCollection.TryGetMap
>   System.Collections.Generic.List`1.get_Item

I can't figure out what's going on here. Why is EF trying to access the list by index, and why it is using an index that doesn't exist? And why would it only be sporadic? The table in question is a simple lookup table whose contents never change.

Comment: Is this code sometimes being run in multiple concurrent threads? Are you reusing your context across multiple calls?

Comment: Yes, it's in a web app, so it probably is. But why would that cause this problem? Are you thinking that locking the thread would prevent the problem?

Comment: I don't recommend trying to implement locking, a better solution would be to lessen the scope of the dictionary, your datacontext or both, so it is not shared across multiple web requests.

Comment: Ah, for simplicity in my code sample, I didn't show that I'm putting this dictionary in HttpRuntime.Cache. That's supposed to be thread safe, but maybe that's a source of trouble. But I still don't get why threading would cause this kind of issue. Is `DbContext` not thread safe?